# Como fazer quebra de linha automática em uma textarea com JavaScript ou jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou fazendo um envio de mensagem e quero colocar o botão como se fosse dentro do textarea, mas o problema é que a escrita passa por debaixo do botão, existe alguma maneira com CSS, javascript ou jQuery de evitar isso?

Segue o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#mostrarMsg").hide();
        
        $('#mensagem').keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13){
                enviarMensagem();
            }
        });
});

function enviarMensagem(){
  var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();
  if(mensagem == "" || mensagem == " " || mensagem == null){
    return;
  }else{
    $("#mostrarMsg").html(mensagem).show();
    $("#mensagem").val('');
  }
}
```

```css
#btnEnviarChat{
    position: inherit;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

#btnEnviarChat:hover{
    
    transition-duration: 1s;
    opacity: 0.9;
    
}

.caixaMensagem{
    resize:none;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<sub>Aperte Enter para enviar</sub>
    <sub id="restante"></sub>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="10" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." class="caixaMensagem"></textarea>
    <button id="btnEnviarChat" onclick="enviarMensagem()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    
    <sub id="mostrarMsg"></sub>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um `padding-right: 60px;` no textarea que o texto não vai chegar no botão:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#mostrarMsg").hide();
        
        $('#mensagem').keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13){
                enviarMensagem();
            }
        });
});

function enviarMensagem(){
  var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();
  if(mensagem == "" || mensagem == " " || mensagem == null){
    return;
  }else{
    $("#mostrarMsg").html(mensagem).show();
    $("#mensagem").val('');
  }
}
```

```css
#btnEnviarChat{
    position: inherit;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

#btnEnviarChat:hover{
    
    transition-duration: 1s;
    opacity: 0.9;
    
}

.caixaMensagem{
    resize:none;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<sub>Aperte Enter para enviar</sub>
    <sub id="restante"></sub>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="10" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." class="caixaMensagem"></textarea>
    <button id="btnEnviarChat" onclick="enviarMensagem()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    
    <sub id="mostrarMsg"></sub>
```